# Subfigures in subfigures - proper alignment

Tags: floats, subfloats

I would like to place three (or more) images such that two images (or four/more) are stacked over each other, while the remaining image is put as a separate column, spanning over all stacked rows. My initial approach was using `subfigure` inside `subfigure`, resulting in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%opening
\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.2\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=4\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{TBA}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill%
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.78\linewidth}
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
            \caption{TBD}
        \end{subfigure}\hfill%
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
            \caption{TBD}
        \end{subfigure}\hfill%
        
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
            \caption{TBD}
        \end{subfigure}\hfill%
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
            \caption{TBD}
        \end{subfigure}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.2\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=4\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{TBA}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill%
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.78\linewidth}
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{.9\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
            \caption{TBD}
        \end{subfigure}\hfill%
        
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{.9\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
            \caption{TBD}
        \end{subfigure}\hfill%
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The second figure illustrates one issue: Figure A which should span along both example figures B is aligned with the caption of the upper fig. B, but I would rather have it aligned with the caption of bottom fig. B.

[image]

How can I do that? When moving fig. A to the end of the subfigure-structure, it just appears to the right of the block consisting of figures B, but is still aligned with the upper caption, not the lower one. Or is it not possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change align argument to `b` (bottom) for second block of subfigures:

`\begin{subfigure}[b]{.78\linewidth}`

---

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%opening
\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.2\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=4\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{TBA}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.78\linewidth}
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
            \caption{TBD}
        \end{subfigure}\hfill%
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
            \caption{TBD}
        \end{subfigure}\hfill%
        
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
            \caption{TBD}
        \end{subfigure}\hfill%
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
            \caption{TBD}
        \end{subfigure}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.2\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=4\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{TBA}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.78\linewidth}
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{.9\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
            \caption{TBD}
        \end{subfigure}\hfill%
        
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{.9\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
            \caption{TBD}
        \end{subfigure}\hfill%
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would (a) remove all `[t]` and `[b]` positioning specifiers and (b) replace the `subfigure` environment that encases the four "inner" `subfigure` environments with a `minipage` environment. (A `subfigure` is a `minipage` that's been told what to do if and when it encounters a `\caption` statement.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \begin{subfigure}{.18\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=3.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{TBDa}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill%
    \begin{minipage}{0.78\textwidth}
        \begin{subfigure}{.475\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
            \caption{TBDb}
        \end{subfigure}\hfill%
        \begin{subfigure}{.475\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
            \caption{TBDc}
        \end{subfigure}
        
        \medskip
        \begin{subfigure}{.475\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
            \caption{TBDd}
        \end{subfigure}\hfill%
        \begin{subfigure}{.475\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
            \caption{TBDe}
        \end{subfigure}
    \end{minipage}
\caption{Overall figure caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```